# Android Shared Element Transition to Menu Item

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I'm working on an Android Lollipop project using Shared Element Transitions.  I would like to create a transition that transitions an ImageButton in Activity A to a Menu Item on Activity B.

```
       <item
            android:id="@+id/project_settings"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_settings_button"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            android:title="settings"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            />
```

This website seems to indicate that transitionName is NOT supported for a menu item, but I don't see any errors in Android studio: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Has anyone successfully done this?